# Listbox text disappears when form loses focus, comes back when we clicked on again

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

*I am sorry in advance that I am providing no code. The reason is simply the fact that I don't know what part of code to put here to be helpful. But here is the problem:*

I have a `Listbox` on my form. When the form starts, the `listbox` will be populated by new items, until the process is finished. There aren't many, say, 10 lines.

All is fine, except when the users click somewhere else on their desktop and the form loses focus. That is when the text inside the `listbox` vanishes. And it comes back once we click on the form again! I have not manipulated the `drawitem` event of the `listbox`. Any ideas why this happens?

**Update**: I realized this also happens when I click on the `listbox` itself! I would also like to add that I have a `label` over my `listbox` control that shows the percentage.

Comment: Any losing focus events on your form?, does the text come back? Are you overriding paint events?

Comment: @Sayse no the only event I have is the `formload`. And yes the text comes back when I click on the form.

Comment: It sounds as though your overriding the painting somewhere... Unless you have another control underneath that listbox and the losing focus brings that to the forefront randomly. How are you adding items to the listbox? `.Add`?

Comment: @Sayse I add message to the listbox in two different ways. One is the normal `listBoxMessages.Items.Add("my message");` and the other is when my `backgroundworker` sends a `progresschanged` event. There is also the case in which I remove the last line of the `listbox` before adding the new item. This is when I would like to display temporary information such as "Subscriber X of 100 added".

Comment: Its going to be really hard to help I'm afraid, I was more fishing at the idea that you may be using `.Text` or similar in which case the storage of the value is not guarranteed. For temporary information, I'd use a MessageBox or a separate label (remove its text after a time)

Comment: To reiterate, the things I would be looking at first would be paint events, any events to do with focus, does this error apply when adding items in different ways, are there any overlapping controls

Comment: @Sayse I cannot use a `MessageBox`because first, my program should also be able to run in a non-interactive mode (background), so communication with the user should be allowed in that case. And second, why should I display a messages such as "Subscriber X of 100 added" that is supposed to be displayed 100 times in a `MessageBox`? This is the reason I started to use a `ListBox` to being with.

Comment: Are items selected? Is hideSelection off? does the border disappear, too? (If it has none, set it for testing!)

Comment: @TaW do you mean `SelectionMode` property of the `ListBox`? It was `One`. But I think it's better if I set it to `None`.

Comment: Whoops, I misread and thought of ListView. The ListBox should be set to whatever is needed. - The question about Borderstyle is about: Is the Listbox or only its content disappearing?

Comment: @TaW It is only the text that disappears. Also please read the update in my question.

Comment: @Pedram - MessageBox doesn't sound like it would suit your needs. However, your update does suggest to me that the overlapping controls may be causing this, does this still happen if they don't overlap? Winforms struggles with overlapping controls and knowing which should be drawn

Comment: @Sayse Good point. I will test without the `label` and come back to you.

Comment: Is the Label __over__ or __in__ the ListBox? (Meaning is it moved over __without__ making the LB its `Parent` or is it part of the LB's `Controls` collection?)

Comment: @TaW I moved the label to another place on the form and I am afraid  the problem still persists. The label is over the listbox and listbox is not its parent.

Comment: Hm. Out of ideas now. Can you do a reality chaeck and add another ListBox to see if it too is affected? Then slowly adjust it more and more till they can be interchanged..

Comment: You need to provide the smallest example of code that recreates the problem so we can test it. Otherwise, the last comment of *TaW* is the best approach.